# Como sabe jQuery la funcionalidad de cada boton?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código de botones para añadir al principio, al final y sustituir el texto desde un area de texto. este es el html:

```
   <section id="menu">
        <textarea class="text" placeholder="type something"></textarea> <br />
        <button id="append">Append</button>
        <button id="prepend">Preppend</button>
        <button id="replace">Replace</button>
    </section>

    <section id="main">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempus leo id nunc elementum, ut rutrum neque ornare. Pellentesque eu ligula lectus. Duis ac tristique est. Fusce finibus convallis sapien, eu faucibus dui elementum eu. Nunc ultrices magna eros, et lobortis tortor egestas vel. Cras finibus quam auctor fermentum facilisis. Nulla facilisi. In pulvinar purus laoreet, imperdiet quam et, laoreet lectus. Donec in consectetur lorem.
            Vestibulum accumsan, velit et bibendum varius, orci est tempor lacus, ut vehicula metus sem a libero. Suspendisse elementum turpis sed lacinia blandit. Phasellus sit amet metus metus. Ut vitae molestie orci. Mauris eu nibh in sapien imperdiet tempor. Etiam rhoncus sapien eget diam vulputate volutpat sit amet vel tortor. Phasellus eget sodales nisl.</p>
    </section>
```

y tengo el siguiente código en jQery para darles funcionalidad y aquí viene mi pregunta: ¿Cómo sabe JS dónde añadir el texto que escribo en la textArea? porque lo puede añadir al principo, al final o sustituir el texto que ya estaba, sin embargo no sé como sabe que hacer con el texto. En ningún momento yo describo dónde debería añadir el nuevo texto.

```
  $("#prepend, #append, #replace").on("click", function(e){  
    var el = $(e.currentTarget);
    var action = el.attr("id");   
    var content = $(".text").val(); 



if(action== "prepend"){
    console.log("prepend");
    $("#main").prepend('<a href="#">', content, '</a>');
}
else if(action == "append"){
    console.log("append");
    $("#main").append(content);

}
else if(action == "replace"){
    console.log("replace");
    $("#main").html(content);
}

$(".text").val("");
  });
```

Comment: Hola, por lo que veo, estas ejecutando los 3 botones a la misma funcionalidad y por eso te sale ese error, por mi parte yo lo haría por cada botón hacer en una función diferente, y funcionará lo que quieres hacer @Juan Vega Seco

Comment: @AlbertArias funciona perfectamente lo que no entiendo es como le da cada funcionalidad a cada botón

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *En ningún momento yo describo dónde debería añadir el nuevo texto*

Eso no es así, te dejo el código pero con los comentarios para que lo veas bien:

```
  //Primero que nada, busca los elementos con id prepend, append y replace y les añade esta función "function(e){}"
$("#prepend, #append, #replace").on("click", function(e){
    //Aquí "e" es el evento disparado
    var el = $(e.currentTarget);  //Asigna a la variable "el" el elemento que ha disparado el evento, es decir, el botón pulsado
    var action = el.attr("id");   //Asigna a la variable action el atributo "id" del elemento(botón), en este caso puede valer
    //"prepend", "append" o "replace" que son los 3 botones diferentes que tienes en el html
    var content = $(".text").val(); //Lee el contenido escrito en el textarea

    if(action== "prepend"){//Lo que hace aquí es mirar si el id del botón, que antes almacenamos en action era "preprend"
        console.log("prepend");
        $("#main").prepend('<a href="#">', content, '</a>');//Añade el contenido al principio usando la función prepend
    }
    else if(action == "append"){//Si el id era "append"
        console.log("append");
        $("#main").append(content);//Añade el contenido al final

    }
    else if(action == "replace"){//Si el id era "replace"
        console.log("replace");
        $("#main").html(content);//Sustituye todo el contenido de la id "main" (en este caso el section) por lo escrito en el textarea
    }

$(".text").val(""); //Finalmente resetea el textarea
});
```

Si hay algo que no entiendes no dudes en preguntar!

Comment: sigo sin ver en que parte especifico que append significa añadir al final, prepend, al principio y replace lo sustituye.

Comment: $("#main"). **append(content)** añade al final, $("#main"). **html(content)** lo sustituye y  $("#main"). **prepend('<a href="#">', content, '</a>');** lo añade al principio. Son los métodos de jQuery los que hacen esa funcionalidad de añadirlo en un lugar u otro. Si te fijas en cada `else if` se llama a un método diferente

Comment: vale, así que son métodos de jQuery los que hacen la funcionalidad. Eso era lo que quería confirmar, gracias

Answer (score 3):

No es que *jQuery* "sepa" la funcionalidad, en tu código se lo estás especificando:

```
$("#prepend, #append, #replace").on("click", function(e){
    // e = Evento disparado
    // e.currentTarget = Elemento que disparó el evento
    // Finalmente, "el" es el botón en que se hizo clic
    var el = $(e.currentTarget);
    // Se toma ID del botón para saber qué hacer:
    //    prepend, append o replace
    var action = el.attr("id");   
    var content = $(".text").val(); 
    // ...
}
```

De acuerdo a las acciones definidas:

- prepend: Agregar contenido al inicio con el método [`.prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)
- append: Agregar contenido al final con el método [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)
- replace: Remplazar contenido con el método [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: sigo sin ver en que parte especifico que append significa añadir al final, prepend, al principio y replace lo sustituye.

Comment: Son métodos establecidos en _jQuery_, por ejemplo: `$('#id_elemento').prepend('Nuevo contenido');` para agregar al inicio. Ante dudas, puedes consultar el manual: [$.prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: Agregué la referencia a cada método en la respuesta.